# How to create custom dropdownlist in kendo grid header column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Actually my requirement is want to create custom dropdownlist in the column header of kendo grid. I don't  down like nrwant to use filtler column. I just want to add normal dropdown in header. Please provide any example like that so that i can move forward on my task.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your column definition add a property like this:

```
headerTemplate: '<input id="dropdown" />'
```

Then after your grid initialization do:
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({...init parameters...});

UPDATE: go to dojo.telerik.com and paste in the following code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { 
      field: "ProductName", 
      title: "Product Name",
      headerTemplate: '<input id="dropdown" />'
    },
    { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Price", template: 'Price: #: kendo.format("{0:c}", UnitPrice)#' }
  ],
  pageable: true,
  dataSource: {
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
        dataType: "jsonp"
      }
    },
    pageSize: 10
  },
  excelExport: function(e) {
    var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
    var template = kendo.template(this.columns[1].template);

    for (var i = 1; i < sheet.rows.length; i++) {
      var row = sheet.rows[i];

      var dataItem = {
         UnitPrice: row.cells[1].value
      };

      row.cells[1].value = template(dataItem);
    }
  }
});

  $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: 'Choose a value...',
    dataTextField: 'description',
    dataValueField: 'id',
    dataSource:{
       data: [{id: 1, description: 'One'},{id: 2, description: 'Two'}]
    },
    change: function(e){
      //do whatever you need here, for example:
      var theGrid = $("#grid").getKendoGrid();
      var theData = theGrid.dataSource.data();
      $(theData).each(function(index,item){
        item.ProductName = e.sender.text();
      });
      theGrid.dataSource.data(theData);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/@rkonstantinov/afOxa) can help you. There is dropdown in first header. (it is with filter functionality, but it can be removed if not needed)

Comment: Thanks Ademar. I'm adding my own example too since I already put it together. It didn't work in JSFiddle, not sure why, so I won't post a link to that, but go to dojo.telerik.com and paste in the following code. It adds a dropdown and changes all the values in the column (replace with whatever functionality you need):